# IE css alignment issues on search box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a search button and search box, I have this working in google chrome but not IE or mobile Safari/Chrome.

The CSS I am using is:

> ```
> #search input {
>   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
>   padding: 10px;
>   border: 0 none;
>   color: #7F7F7F;
>   font: 20px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
>   transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
>   width: 500px;
>   height: 40px;
>   margin: 0 auto;
>   display: inline-block;
> }
>
> #search button {
> padding: 21px;
>   background: url("search.png") no-repeat scroll center center #7eac10;
>   cursor: pointer;
>   height: 60px;
>   text-indent: -99999em;
>   transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
>   width: 60px;
>   border: 2px solid #fff;
>   margin: 0 auto;
>   display: inline-block;
>   margin-top: 3%;
> }
> ```

HTML:

> 

```
<form id="search" action="/index.php">
> 
> <p><b></b> <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Enter A
> Domain Name or IP address."name="domain" id="domain" value=""> 
> <button value="lookup"></p></button> </form>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

The web address is http://rapidwhois.uk

Comment: please post the html markup

Comment: your html is not valid. please consider moving `</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try:

```
#search button, #search input {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it is now doing the same thing in chrome.

Comment: @JamesDawson you still need to get rid of the margin-top on your button or the space will remain on the button, now its simply unified across browsers, as soon as you remove the margin, it will be aligned perfectly

Comment: @JamesDawson the different and unnecessary padding,margin,font-size, and height for the two element, makes your  layout difficult to handle. please rewrite those, once for both elements

Answer (score 0):

Well you have other issues on your layout as well, but the basic problem is the fact that you are missing the correct `vertical-align` in your CSS.

Simply add in `vertical-align: text-top` to both the INPUT and the BUTTON tags and remove the margin from the button and you are set.

Then you simply need to use a padding on the container element in order to get the same layout as before. (Would give you a better example, but you do not have an isolated test case and I simply confirmed this in my IE.)

Answer (score 0):

Here this should do it for you, wrap the button with a label like this

```
  <label for="btn">
        <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Enter A Domain Name or IP address."name="domain" id="domain" value=""/>
<button id="btn" value="lookup">lookup</button>
     </label>
```